# MySQL Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1452

I am trying to insert values into the employee table but when I tried to execute the script, it gave me this error. What am I doing wrong?

RESPONSE:

> Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key
> constraint fails (`smolcompany`.`employee`, CONSTRAINT `employee_fk2`
> FOREIGN KEY (`DeptID`) REFERENCES `department` (`DeptID`) ON DELETE
> RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE)

ACTION:

> INSERT INTO employee  VALUES (4283, 'Sarim Mansoor', 'M', 27, 'Mont
> Kiara', NULL, 102), (4465, 'Teh Yi Heng', 'M', 23, 'Cyberjaya', NULL,
> 101), (4123, 'Thamal Kishen', 'F', 47, 'Petaling Jaya', 4283, 102),
> (3978, 'Mike Ross', 'M', 26, 'Mont Kiara', NULL, 103), (5240, 'Martha
> Arnold', 'F', 27, 'Mont Kiara', 4465, 101)

TABLE:

```
CREATE TABLE employee 
(
EmpID INT NOT NULL,
EmpName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
EmpGender CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
EmpAge INT NOT NULL,
EmpAddress VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
SuperID INT,
DeptID INT NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT employee_pk PRIMARY KEY(EmpID),
CONSTRAINT employee_uk UNIQUE(EmpName),
CONSTRAINT employee_ck CHECK(EmpAge>18 AND EmpAge<100),
CONSTRAINT employee_fk1 FOREIGN KEY(SuperID) REFERENCES employee(EmpID) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT
);

CREATE TABLE department 
(
DeptID INT NOT NULL,
DeptName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
DeptBlock CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
DeptLevel INT NOT NULL,
ManagerID INT NOT NULL,
MStartDate DATE NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT department_pk PRIMARY KEY(DeptID),
CONSTRAINT department_uk UNIQUE(DeptName),
CONSTRAINT department_ck CHECK(DeptBlock='A' OR DeptBlock='B' OR DeptBlock='C'),
CONSTRAINT department_fk FOREIGN KEY(ManagerID) REFERENCES employee(EmpID) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT
);

ALTER TABLE employee ADD CONSTRAINT employee_fk2 FOREIGN KEY(DeptID) REFERENCES department(DeptID) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT;
```

VALUES:

```
INSERT INTO employee 
VALUES
(4283, 'Sarim Mansoor', 'M', 27, 'Mont Kiara', NULL, 102),
(4465, 'Teh Yi Heng', 'M', 23, 'Cyberjaya', NULL, 101),
(4123, 'Thamal Kishen', 'F', 47, 'Petaling Jaya', 4283, 102),
(3978, 'Mike Ross', 'M', 26, 'Mont Kiara', NULL, 103),
(5240, 'Martha Arnold', 'F', 27, 'Mont Kiara', 4465, 101);
```

Comment: _Big Note_ Storing an employee's age as `20` is a terrible idea. They will not always be `20` Instead store their DateOfBirth and work out their age when you need it

Comment: With your constrint you cannot store a row with a SuperId of NULL because there is no Employee with an `id` of NULL. I dont think that constraint make any sense at all as it stands

Comment: youu need the Department id 101-103 prior to the employees. But that looks like of ring dependencies, which you shouldn't do as you need one to be prior declared to the other and vice versa

Comment: @RiggsFolly but not all of the employees will have a supervisor, hence some of them are left as NULL. May I ask how I should rewrite the code to make that happen?

Comment: You should accept your own answer if its worked. So, everybody that run into the same problem can follow your solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem, I had to add the constraint

```
ALTER TABLE employee ADD CONSTRAINT employee_fk2 FOREIGN KEY(DeptID) REFERENCES department(DeptID) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT;
```

only after I had created both tables and inserted all the values. Thank you everyone for your suggestions.